# gh-pages -d build hangs on password request

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I've been trying to deploy a REACT app to github pages.

When I type 'npm run deploy' it creates the build as expected. When it comes time to deploy to github pages, it sends the command "gh-pages -d build."

This produces a username field. I type in my username, and it responds by asking for the password. But the problem is that I cannot enter a password. There is no way to type anything. If I try to type anything, nothing happens.

I realize that passwords no longer work, so I would need to enter a personal token. But I can't enter the personal token either because it is impossible to type anything once this happens.

Has anyone else had this problem before, and have you found a way to fix it?

Comment: This is an established security feature - your input is accepted it is just not visible on the screen. Type what you must and press enter, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same issue for a few hours, the only thing you need to do is to create a new personal access token as this explains: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token
Then on the terminal type your user and copy paste the token as the pasword.